# Multiple Disqus instances in one site

Tags: disqus

Are there any issues with running two distinct Disqus instances (ie different shortnames) within the one domain? I need to run separate instances on a blog and on a news section, mainly to allow different administrators for each, along with different settings (ie different requirements around commentor authentication).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no concern, but you will need to make sure you don't set multiple distinct shortnames on a single page, since we only read the last one.

This most commonly comes up when using the comment counting `count.js` script, since it also uses `var disqus_shortname` just like the embed.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, didn't think it would be a problem but wanted to make sure before I implemented